# Cannot set multiple images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting buffered image/jpeg from backend. Parent component does setState every time a new image is received and is passed down to Child component.

Child Component receives every update and can be seen in console logs, but it is only displaying single image.

**Parent component:**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      nodeResponse: ''
  }
}

getFileStatusFromNode = (data) => {
    this.setState({nodeResponse: data})
  }

render() {

let CardView = nodeResponse !== '' &&
  <Card key={nodeResponse.fileName} name={nodeResponse.fileName} image={nodeResponse.buffer} />


return (
      <div className="App tc">
         { CardView }
      </div>
     )
   }
}
```

**Child component:**

```
class Card extends PureComponent {
  constructor({props}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      src: '',
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
  console.log("Card mounted")
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        src: [this.props.image, ...prevState.src]
      }), () => console.log(this.state.src, this.props.name));
}

render() {
  const { name } = this.props;
  const { src } = this.state;

 return (

      <a style={{width: 200, height: 250}} key={name} className={'tc'} >
      <div id='images'>
      <img style={{width: 175, height: 175}} className='tc' alt='missing' src={`data:image/jpeg;base64, ${src}`}/>
      </div>
      </a> 
    )
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** These images are coming from socket io. I want to display them in real time rather than creating a list first and then display together.

Comment: You only render one `Card` which in turns render one only image; you need some kind list of  `Card` to render multiple images

Comment: @Dario How can I create a list? I want to display images as soon as they are received to client. I thought react would just update the DOM.

Comment: You could use array where you push images as soon as you receive them. Then in your render you use `map` on this array to render one `Card` for every image.

Comment: Make use props and conditional rendering.

Comment: @Dario Pls check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You are only rendering 1 `<Card>` when defining the `<CardView>` component.

Assuming `nodeResponse.imageFiles` is an array of files, you should have something like the following:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      nodeResponse: ''
  }
}

getFileStatusFromNode = (data) => {
    this.setState({nodeResponse: data})
  }

render() {

let CardView

if(this.state.nodeResponse !== '') {
  CardView = this.state.nodeResponse.imageFiles.map(file => (
     <Card
       key={image.fileName}
       name={image.fileName}
       image={image.buffer} />
  )
)}

return (
      <div className="App tc">
         { CardView }
      </div>
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: it is not an array of images.
This is what I get from backend.
```{image: true, buffer: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QC8RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAA…7Rwi1CurtiD8oFKlVJDJN4BFxMSTxUGW6dBxSpUxGWTZ//9k=", fileName: "425201911918PM-robo.jpg"}```

Comment: You'll need to store the images that your received earlier in some sort of state. When you get the new image from the API call, push it into an array of images stored in the component state. Then you can follow my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      nodeResponse: []
    }
  }

  getFileStatusFromNode = (data) => {
    // here you merge the previous data with the new
    const nodeResponse = [...this.state.nodeResponse, data];
    this.setState({ nodeResponse: nodeResponse });
  }

  render() {
   return (<div className="App tc">
      {this.state.nodeResponse.map(n => <Card key={n.fileName} name={n.fileName} image={n.buffer} />)}
   </div>);
  }
}
```

and in your child component

```
class Card extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { src } = this.props;

   return (<a style={{width: 200, height: 250}} className="tc">
      <div id='images'>
        <img style={{width: 175, height: 175}} className='tc' alt='missing' src={`data:image/jpeg;base64, ${src}`}/>
      </div>
    </a>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't we mutating state nodeResponse directly? I think the variable name should be different.